# Aggregate cidrs up to a limit

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address

I have this algorithm which aggregates a list of cidrs up to a provided limit based on the distance between them. It finds the closest ones and calculates the subnet to join them. The loop repeats until the limit is reached. I think there's room to improve it but I'm stuck at the moment. Any advice?

**Input**

- limit: 9
- cidrs (10):

  ```
  52.1.0.0/16
  52.2.0.0/16
  52.3.0.0/16
  52.4.0.0/16
  52.5.0.0/16
  52.6.0.0/16
  52.7.0.0/16
  52.8.0.0/16
  52.9.0.0/16
  52.10.0.0/16
  ```

**Output**

- cidrs (9):

  ```
  52.1.0.0/16
  5̶2̶.̶2̶.̶0̶.̶0̶/̶1̶6̶
  5̶2̶.̶3̶.̶0̶.̶0̶/̶1̶6̶
  52.4.0.0/16
  52.5.0.0/16
  52.6.0.0/16
  52.7.0.0/16
  52.8.0.0/16
  52.9.0.0/16
  52.10.0.0/16
  **52.2.0.0/15**
  ```

**Code**

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Aggregate(List<string> cidrs, int limit)
{
    var parsedCidrs = cidrs.Select(IPNetwork.Parse).ToArray();

    var cidr1 = parsedCidrs[0];
    var cidr2 = parsedCidrs[1];
    var minWideSubnet = IPNetwork.WideSubnet(new[] { cidr1, cidr2 });

    while (parsedCidrs.Count > limit)
    {
        foreach (var cidrA in parsedCidrs)
        {
            foreach (var cidrB in parsedCidrs)
            {
                if (cidrA != cidrB)
                {
                    var wideSubnet = IPNetwork.WideSubnet(new[] {cidrA, cidrB});

                    if (wideSubnet.Usable < minWideSubnet.Usable)
                    {
                        minWideSubnet = wideSubnet;
                        cidr1 = cidrA;
                        cidr2 = cidrB;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // update array
        cidrs.Remove(cidr1.ToString());
        cidrs.Remove(cidr2.ToString());
        var end = minWideSubnet.ToString();
        cidrs.Add(end);
    }

    return cidrs;
}
```

Comment: Where can I find the `IPNetwork` type?

Comment: nuget. https://goo.gl/Q1pjLF @t3chb0t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just a small cosmetic improvement: I'd call the method `MergeSimilarIps` or something like this (you know better what name would make more sense). Aggregate suggests you would get a sigle result.

---

> ```
>     foreach (var cidrA in parsedCidrs)
>     {
>         foreach (var cidrB in parsedCidrs)
>         {
>             if (cidrA != cidrB)
>             {
> ```

I thnink you can speed the merge a little bit by using `for` loops and starting the second one at `i + 1` of the first loop. This way you check `x == y` only once because `y == x` is the same an you already checked it so there is no need that you do it again plus the `+ 1` will skip `x == x`.

Compare these two loops. The first one works like in your solution:

```
var nums = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach (var x in nums)
{
    foreach (var y in nums)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"({x}, {y})");
    }
}
```

its result is:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
```

The second one works without repetitions.

```cs
for (var x = 0; x < nums.Length; x++)
{
    for (var y = x + 1; y < nums.Length; y++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"({nums[x]}, {nums[y]})");
    }
}
```

It produces only 1/3 of this list above:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

This means you get only unique combinations without repetitions.

Comment: Good point too the x+1 so we can avoid some repetition. I'm thinking about the while loop as the last improvement factor. We might save some cycles by storing compared items, that way we might reduce the processing time, what do you think? Good point the function name too.

Comment: @tribet you don't need to store the compared items because each combination will be compared only once. With these loops there is no more `x == x` or `y == y`. There is only `x == y` because `y == x` means the same and the loops skip those. The next time you run the `while` you should have new items to compare this is, the results of a merge. I think it's better to add a new flag `var merged = false;` and set it to `true` if some addressed could be merged. If there were no more merges you don't need to run to the end of the limit. You can stop as soon as no merges took place.

Comment: A merge happens on every iteration of the while loop. By saving the usable value somehow I can prevent operations that already took place. Probably a sorted list might ease the job.